# Hibernate mapping multiple classes to one table using hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, mapping, hibernate-mapping

I am fairly new to Hibernate and need some help with hibernate-mapping.

I have 4 different classes which I want to map into one table, of which the primary key consists of attributes from 2 different classes. At the same time, I want to map only selected attributes from each class into a local database. I wish to avoid JPA annotations and define the mapping style in a hbm.xml file instead. How do I do that?

Take the following example:

```
public class Tenant implements Serializable {
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected List<Rack> rack;
    protected String type;
    //getters setters
}

public class Rack implements Serializable {
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;        
    protected List<Circuit> circuit;
    protected String rackLabel;
    protected Boolean excludes;
    //getters setters
}

public class Circuit implements Serializable {
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected List<CircuitReadings> circuitReadings;
    protected String circuitNo;
    protected Boolean excludes;
    //getters setters
}

public class CircuitReadings
    implements Serializable {
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected String date;
    protected String kva;
    protected String current;
    protected String kwh;
    //getters setters
}
```

And the eventual table should consist of the following:

```
    type | rackLabel | circuitNo | date | kva | current | energy
```

"circuitNo" and "date" above should form the composite primary keys.

Can someone show me an example of how I should map this? Thanks!

Comment: Why add all four classes in a single table? From the way they look, all classes have a many to one relationship between them. Adding all of them in a single table would yield a very de-normalized table. This is usually a bad thing in relational databases.

Comment: This is because I don't want to store all attributes to the database, and want only selected ones. the attributes I want are highlighted in the table description above. My solution was to create a separate method that loops through the "Tenant" object and its sub classes, and consolidate only values I want stored into the database into a separate class e.g. ClassA. A hbm file is then created for ClassA. I know it's not ideal to do this, hence, i'm looking for a more optimal solution.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate provide a way to map subclass using discriminator keyword.

```
<class name="Payment" table="PAYMENT">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="PAYMENT_ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="PAYMENT_TYPE" type="string"/>
    <property name="amount" column="AMOUNT"/>
    ...
    <subclass name="CreditCardPayment" discriminator-value="CREDIT">
        <join table="CREDIT_PAYMENT">
            <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
            <property name="creditCardType" column="CCTYPE"/>
            ...
        </join>
    </subclass>
    <subclass name="CashPayment" discriminator-value="CASH">
        <join table="CASH_PAYMENT">
            <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
            ...
        </join>
    </subclass>
    <subclass name="ChequePayment" discriminator-value="CHEQUE">
        <join table="CHEQUE_PAYMENT" fetch="select">
            <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
            ...
        </join>
    </subclass>
</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you from doing that . Create 4 HBMs pointing to the same table but different Pojos . Though it can be done , as @Ioan Alexandru Cucu , it is not recommended .

```
   <!-- HBM1-->

<class name="com.myProject.Rack"
    table="My_Table">

   <!-- HBM2-->

   <class name="com.myProject.Rack"
    table="My_Table">
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand how this would work. Referring back to my example,, how do I specify in the hbm that I want to repeat the same "circuitNo" for each "date", "kva", "current", and "energy" in the "CircuitReadings" list?